# Using grep for an entire file

Tags: bash, grep

I've got a list with 250 lines in it. I have to run all of them through a web server to get a list of output. This list, however returns many more lines, than I'm interested in. Say, my list.txt is:

```
a.1
b.1
etc
```

then the output is output.txt:

```
a.1 a b c
a.2 b a b
a.3 d k o
b.1 b o p
b.2 o i y
b.3 p i y
etc
```

Is it possible to use the grep command to search for all words in `list.txt` in the `output.txt` and then generate "the wanted" list `wanted.txt`?

I need the entire line in my `output.txt`

I've asked this question on AskUnuntu but they've sent me here. I was suggested this command

```
$ grep -wFf list.txt output.txt
```

but I'm prompted with a `grep: out of memory`.

Is there a simplish way to do this for a beginner like me?

Comment: May you please clarify what your input is and how do you want your output?

Comment: Out of memory for a 250 line file? Are you running it on an IBM 5150 ?

Comment: No... I have a macbook pro. it's brand new.

Comment: My input is a file containing 250 words (one in each line). I want to use each line/word to find the corresponding line in the output.txt and make a new file wanted.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one-liner reads every line in `list.txt` and greps for it in `output.txt` (assuming you want to match only lines with the word at the beginning, and only if it is a word of its own):

```
while read word ; do grep -w "^$word" output.txt ; done < list.txt > wanted.txt
```

Using the provided example input plus the following lines

```
a.1bar
fooa.1
foo a.1 bar
```

`wanted.txt` contains:

```
a.1 a b c
b.1 b o p
```

Note that this solution is less elegant than using `grep -f`, but may address your specific memory problem (untested).

Comment: That's exactly what I want. However, it gives me only an empty wanted.txt file :(

Comment: and at the same time `cat list.txt` works? what about `echo test>wanted.txt`?

Comment: what about `cat output.txt` and `while read word ; do echo "$word" ; done < list.txt > wanted.txt`?

Comment: That means all of the files are in your working directory and your user has permission to create files there. I have tested using Bash 4.1.5, but as my command uses only compatible shell syntax and OS X `grep` supports the `-w` option, I really can't see what could be going wrong on your machine.

Comment: I dont' know... But thank you so much for trying to help me. Guess I'll have to do it by hand :(