# How to grep all the numbers in a file

Tags: bash

```
$ cat test 
1
0
2

Operator
3

$ cat test ¦ grep [0-9] 
1
```

The test file contains the above values. When I grep the test file using `grep [0-9]` it gives only `1` as output. How to grep all the numbers in the test file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using grep for an entire file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982539/using-grep-for-an-entire-file)

Comment: `¦` is no pipe. This might help: `cat file | grep '[0-9]'` or shorter `grep '[0-9]' file`

Comment: @priya : Assuming that you replace the broken bar by a vertical bar, or get rid of the unnecessary `cat`, as Cyrus suggested, it is NOT the case that you will get only 1 as output. Instead, the output will be any line which contains a digit.  For instance, if you replace _Operator_ by _Operator21_, this line will be output too.

Answer (score 0):

#### awk:

```
awk -F'[^0-9]*' '$0=$2
```

#### grep:

```
grep -x -E '[[:digit:]]+'
grep -o -E '[0-9]+'
```

#### sed:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```

#### echo:

```
echo "${string//[!0-9]/}"
echo "${string//[^0-9]/}"
echo "${string//[a-z,.]/}"
```

#### tr

```
tr -d -c 0-9
```